# How to create dictionary from nested list

Tags: python, list, dictionary, nested

```
players=[['Jim','16','2'], ['John','5','1'], ['Jenny','1','0']]
lst=['score', 'win']
```

I have the above lists. I wish to create a output as follows:

```
{'Jim': {'score': 16, 'won': 2}, 'John': {'score': 5, 'won': 1}, 'Jenny': {'score': 1, 'won': 0}}
```

Is it possible?

Answer (score 2):

You can use unpacking with `zip`:

```
players=[['Jim','16','2'], ['John','5','1'], ['Jenny','1','0']]
lst=['score', 'win']
results = {a:dict(zip(lst, [int(i) for i in b])) for a, *b in players}
```

Output:

```
{'Jim': {'score': 16, 'win': 2}, 'John': {'score': 5, 'win': 1}, 'Jenny': {'score': 1, 'win': 0}}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's one solution which also converts values to integers:

```
res = {name: dict(zip(lst, map(int, scores))) for name, *scores in players}

{'Jenny': {'score': 1, 'win': 0},
 'Jim': {'score': 16, 'win': 2},
 'John': {'score': 5, 'win': 1}}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> players=[['Jim','16','2'], ['John','5','1'], ['Jenny','1','0']]
>>> lst=['score', 'win']
>>> a = {}
>>> for player in players:
    a[player[0]] = {lst[0]:player[1],lst[1]:player[2]}

>>> a
{'Jim': {'score': '16', 'win': '2'}, 'John': {'score': '5', 'win': '1'}, 'Jenny': {'score': '1', 'win': '0'}}
>>>
```